# python html table is only getting first row

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse historical data for Bitcoin.  Instead of getting 30 in 30 rows, I'm getting one days repeated 30 times.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/"

r = requests.get(url)

html_content = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"html.parser")

for tr  in soup.find_all('tr')[6]:
   tds = soup.find_all('td')
   print ("date: %s, Open: %s, High:%s,  Low: %s,  Close: %s, Volume: %s, Marketcap: %s\n" % \
     (tds[0].text,tds[1].text,tds[2].text,tds[3].text,tds[4].text, tds[5].text, tds[6].text))
```

Here's the output:

```
date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000

date: May 29, 2018, Open: 7129.46, High:7526.42,  Low: 7090.68,  Close: 7472.59, Volume: 5,662,660,000, Marketcap: 121,636,000,000
```

I should be getting data for the dates, Apr 30 - May 29

What am I missing?

Comment: you must loop through all the td's in your tr variable, but you are finding td's again in your for loop (this will result in finding all td's in one array)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate to question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309550/python-beautifulsoup-iterate-over-table]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python beautifulsoup iterate over table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309550/python-beautifulsoup-iterate-over-table)

Answer (score -1):

You can apply a variable for all data like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"html.parser")
i=1

for trs in soup.find('table'):
    # tds = soup.find_all('td')
    i=i+1
    print(trs.text)
print(i)
```