# How to iterate through elements in an HTML file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

This is the page I am looking at: https://www.nytimes.com/topic/destination/russia

I have imported BeautifulSoup and requests. I want to create a text file with all the headlines from this page. I can get one of them, using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/topic/destination/russia').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
headline = soup.find('h2').get_text()
print(headline)
```

which yields:

```
When an Oil Price War Meets Coronavirus Fears, Markets Get Punched in the Face
```

All good. However, I am utterly lost on how to iterate through and collect all the headlines from the page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python beautifulsoup iterate over table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309550/python-beautifulsoup-iterate-over-table)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Python+beautifulsoup+iterate

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? It sounds like you just need to learn how to use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Does my answer help you? if so dont forget to click the tick next to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for headline in soup.find_all('h2'):
    print(healdine.get_text())
```

The `find_all` returns all `<h2>` tag as a list. Now iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_all()` to get all the headings.

Use a `for` loop to get the text from each and print.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/topic/destination/russia').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
headings = soup.find_all('h2')
for h in headings:
    heading = h.get_text()
    print(heading)
```