# Assigning variables to scraped values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using beautifulsoup to scrape a website (this guy as an example here:https://rocket-league.com/player/Guuter), I have managed to get the text I want.  However, I do not know how to properly assign each string to certain variables to after format them correctly.  It is a trading website so I want to separate the trade into the "has" and "wants" section

Where I have got so far (btw the massive gaps are included):

```
Has:



#first item
Titanium White #colour

Credits #item


200 #amount




#second item
Titanium White #colour

Credits #item


250 #amount

Wants:




Titanium White #colour

Neo-Thermal #item

#no amount this time - therefore is 1





#second item
Grey #colour

Halo #item

#once again no amount - therefore is 1
```

It is a discord bot that when you look up someone's name with a command it gives you their first trade (would like to be more - please let me know how to do this - not letting me use find_all without an error)

```py
@bot.command()
async def rlgarage(ctx, arg):
 name = arg
 #name = "Guuter"
 page = requests.get("https://rocket-league.com/player/"+name)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

 tradeitems = soup.find(class_="rlg-trade__items")
 haveitems = tradeitems.find(class_="rlg-trade__itemshas")
 haveitemstext = haveitems.get_text()
 wantitems = tradeitems.find(class_="rlg-trade__itemswants")
 wantitemstext = wantitems.get_text()
 await ctx.send("Has:" + haveitemstext + "Wants:" + wantitemstext)
```

prefered output:

```
Has:

Titanium White Credits (200)

Titanium White Credits (250)

Wants:

Titanium White Neo-Thermal

Grey Halo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken items from `a` tag and append into `lst` and used join operation on by dividing into 2 parts you can use this code but if total items only were 2 on web page you can put condition to handle it

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://rocket-league.com/player/Guuter")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tradeitems = soup.find("div",class_="rlg-trade__items")
lst=[]
for i in tradeitems.find_all("a"):
    lst.append(i.get_text(strip=True,separator=" "))
print("Has :\n"+"\n".join(lst[:2])+"\nWants :\n"+"\n".join(lst[2:]))
```

Output:

```
Has :
Titanium White Credits 200
Titanium White Credits 250
Wants :
Titanium White Neo-Thermal
Grey Halo
```

Comment: ty works perfectly - mind if i ask 1. how it works with the a tags? - 2. how can I repeat this for multiple trades - so it lists multiple

Comment: You have done for one now you can do for multiple using `find_all` in tradeitmes

Comment: which do I find_all?

Comment: See  i have mention that we have taken one `tradeitem` now use `find_all` method and iterate over that again find `a tag` and append data to list and use that data try it!

Comment: sry but when using ```tradeitems = soup.find_all("div",...``` I get ```AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?```

Comment: what is your class name??

Comment: sorry class for...?

Comment: ```
tradeitems = soup.find_all("div",class_="rlg-trade__items")
```
?

Comment: i guess it should work and it is working in my notebook!

Comment: is this not right?

`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
arg = "Guuter"
page = requests.get("https://rocket-league.com/player/"+arg)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tradeitems = soup.find_all("div",class_="rlg-trade__items")
lst=[]
for i in tradeitems.find_all("a"):
    lst.append(i.get_text(strip=True,separator=" "))
print("Has :\n"+"\n".join(lst[:2])+"\nWants :\n"+"\n".join(lst[2:]))`

Comment: here is my replit if it helps: https://replit.com/@Pricysquirrl/OpenUnknownRegister#main.py

Comment: `for i in tradeitems.find_all("a"):` see tradeitems return list of items and your finding a-tag using find_all which does not make any sense you need 2 loops i have clearly mention in above comments try from your end once!

Comment: so sorry would you mind giving me some code as an example? - I dont really understand

Comment: [see post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10309647/11583070) from here he is getting only first th row but if he needs to find all  the rows simple again use for loop

Comment: sorry for the dumb questions - but would you mind explaining with code an example relevant to here - I am a beginner so its quite hard to understand someone else's code